# Access Web Database Migration, Poor VPN and remote performance

Tags: ms-access, networking, vpn

I have a broad question that I would like some advice on.

Currently, I have a number of databases in a shared location on our company's network. When at the office, these can be accessed quickly (but through VPN, it's slow).

We have multiple locations around the country and can access the drives of each location to pull up excel sheets, pdf's, etc. The problem is, Access applications are **Extremely** slow when accessing another location's shared drive.

Is there anything that can be done to increase performance other than migrating to SQL server and using a web-based app? Just looking for general advice here.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use remote desktop to a machine on that LAN. The thing is, there's going to be multiple people using this app, most of which aren't computer literate. Web database was my first thought. I haven't used web services with Access and was thinking that could be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the VPN is slow is well because your VPN is likely 50 to 100 times slower than your LAN (local area network).  In effect you asking the following question:

Why does it take longer to walk to the store then to drive to the store? 
Answer:
 because you going slower along the way (not really rocket science here).

A few solutions are:

Consider moving the back end data part to SQL server. So while ADP's are being depreciated, this in no way affects the great choice and suggestion to keep the Access application as a front end and move the tables (data) to SQL server.

If you only need a few forms, then Access 2010 (and 2013) does now support web publishing. Here is a video of an Access application of mine, and note how at half way point I switch to running the application in a standard browser:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

As noted, another great solution is to use some type of remote desktop solution. I explain why your connection is slow and give some suggestions for using Access on a  WAN here:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.htm

So the basic issue here is your VPN is too slow and is far slower then your LAN.

Comment: So basically the remote desktop solution would take control of a machine that's physically located on the same network as the database? So assuming control of a machine remotely would have a higher performance than using the database remotely? The only instance that I used something like this was using microsoft lync to control a buddy's PC that was located on the same network(drive) as the database -- Which was faster than me connecting to the network and doing it myself.

Comment: Yes, correct. Yes, you wind up only sending screen updates, mouse clicks and keyboard strokes down the network pipe. There is a significant amount of the IT industry that has adopted solutions around this concept. The mainstream and tried and true solutions are Windows Terminal Services and Citrix. (BinGoole those keywords). Citrix and TS are quite much the same technology. So these are "enterprise" solutions built around users connecting to a remote desktop. These solutions work well in low bandwidth solutions and are common solutions known to those with experience in the IT field.

Comment: I'll look into this. Would this mean that there should just basically be a computer on each network that would be essentially 'dedicated' for remote desktop use?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase performance over slow connections of an Access Database.  There is no server serving records to the client, so Access has to download the whole dataset to do operations on it.  You don't have to have a we-based app, though.

You can try to convert your .mdb to a .adp, or access data project.  If successful, you will still use Access as the client, but all your data would be migrated to SQL Server.  Queries on this data will be handled by the server, and you will see drastic performance improvements over slow connections.

Comment: Note that Microsoft is deprecating ADP support beginning with Access 2013.  You may need a different approach if you want your application to run under future Access versions.